# Selenium Python: How to web scrape the element text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to webscrap data from roulette game.
While trying to

```
find element by class name (roulette_round_result-position__text)
```

I am getting this output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4f20fd17bf4037ed8cf50b00e844a7f", element="f12cf837-6c77-4c90-9da2-7b5fb9da9e5d")>
```

Any idea how to scrap this value? (In this case number 2)

My code:

```
number_1=0
    while number_1 == 0:
        try:
            number_1 = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('roulette-round-result-position__text')
        except:
            pass
```

Screen shot from DevTools:

[image: Screen shot from DevTools]

Comment: print(number1.text) To get the text out. Also include the html as code not a screenshot.

Comment: Also make sure your class name is unique otherwise you would just get another element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are printing the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). Hence you see the output as:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4f20fd17bf4037ed8cf50b00e844a7f", element="f12cf837-6c77-4c90-9da2-7b5fb9da9e5d")>
```

Instead you may like to print the *text* within the element as:

```
number_1 = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('roulette-round-result-position__text')
print(number_1.text)
```

or

```
print(self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('roulette-round-result-position__text').text)
```

Comment: Thank you for solving this problem