# Selenium send_keys doesn't send uppercase R within the input bar

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium 4.1.0 and I'm trying to send 'CRISTIAN' in an input bar through

```
input_bar.send_keys('CRISTIAN')
```

But it shows 'CISTIAN' in the bar.
I've tried also tried:

```
ActionChains(driver).click(input_bar).send_keys('CRISTIAN', Keys.ENTER).perform()`
```

But I get the same result. I checked all the uppercase letters and I figured out that only R have this problem. Any suggestions? Does it depends on this version of Selenium?

**HTML of the input bar:**

```html
<div _ngcontent-qhp-c128="" cdkdroplist="" cdkdroplistorientation="horizontal" cdkdroplistdisabled="" class="cdk-drop-list d-flex flex-1 cdk-drop-list-disabled" id="cdk-drop-list-16"><input _ngcontent-qhp-c128="" cdkdrag="" data-bp="input" class="cdk-drag comp-input mt-2 cdk-drag-disabled" placeholder="Aggiungi elemento"><!----><!----><!----><!----></div>
```

Comment: Can you try assigning value to the input_bar using JS in browser console?

Comment: @RohitBabu yes, it works with JS in the browser console

Comment: Could you show your HTML DOM or if possible share the website link. I tried with Google's searchbar, and it worked. Also, is there any specific reason to use such a long way (using action chains). You could send input directly as well, like this: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your_element").send_keys('CRISTIAN')`. XPATH is one of the strategies, but any other locator strategy may also be used.

Comment: @AnandGautam I've attached the HTML. I find the element through XPATH and I use send_keys but I get the same problem

Comment: @marco please use code format (copy paste the code) for HTML instead of img format

Comment: @AnandGautam did it

Comment: @marco It works for me: `x = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
x.send_keys('CRISTIAN')
y = x.get_attribute('value')
print(y)` . Here is the output:  `CRISTIAN

Process finished with exit code 0`.  I suspect there could be system setting in your machine that's affecting you, but I am not sure of it.

Comment: @AnandGautam I use macOS Monterey 12.1, Chrome 99.0.4844.51, webdriver v99

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to send a *character sequence* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id^='cdk-drop-list'][cdkdroplistorientation='horizontal'] input[class*='cdk-drag'][data-bp='input'][placeholder='Aggiungi elemento']"))).send_keys('CRISTIAN')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@cdkdroplistorientation='horizontal' and starts-with(@id, 'cdk-drop-list')]//input[contains(@class, 'cdk-drag') and @data-bp='input'][@placeholder='Aggiungi elemento']"))).send_keys('CRISTIAN')
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I already use these locators to get the input bar but none of them work

Comment: @marco More then [_locator strategies_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) it's about synchronization using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447).

Comment: What do you mean by synchronization? Can you explain it better?

Comment: Did you get a chance to visit the embedded links within the answer?

Comment: yes but I still can figure out why an R in a word can affect the synchronization

Comment: It's the other way round. Synchronization is needed to overcome the time needed for rendering of the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447).