# Selenium Python in Wordpress how to add multiple h2 titles

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to add multiple h2 titles but in WordPress Classic Editor the h2 titles show up only like that -
[image: this is how the code looks]

there are no identifiers

The code now

```
   driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[1]/di v[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/button').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/iframe")))
    driver.send.keys('text')
```

IDK why the code looks weird like that, but now it just adds the h2 title. Since when I add it and it's active is there a way to `.send_keys('mt text')` but by not clicking on the h2?

Answer (score 1):

The approach to send text through *`send_keys()`* is incorrect here.

[`send_keys()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) is a [webelement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) method. So you need to invoke the method on [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) only.

Your effective code block will be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/iframe")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//body[@id="tinymce" and @data-id="content"]').send.keys('mt text')
```