# Extract title but give me wrong output using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager





options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#chrome to stay open to see what's happening in the real word or make it comment to close
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)   

URL ='https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/'
driver.get(URL)

title=driver.find_element("xpath", '//ul[@class="letter-filter"]//li[1]')
title.click()

page_links = [element.get_attribute('href') for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='name']//a")]

for link in page_links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3"))).text)

driver.close()
```

I want to extract the `name` but they extract the name in different format they will give me output like these page link is https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/abdullaev_parviz_zairhan_ogly/

```
\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2
```

but I want output these:

```
Абдуллаев Парвиз Заирхан оглы
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `name=driver.find_element("xpath", '//h3').text.encode('utf-8')`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what effect do you expect the `.encode('utf-8')` part to have? Did you try leaving this out? What happens if you leave it out? (If you don't understand why this happens, please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html .)

Comment: The output you got just looks like a Python byte string https://stackoverflow.com/a/6224384/150978. Have you tried to decode it to a character string?

Comment: @Robert rather than decoding, it would be better not to encode it in the first place, as the string was already present in the code.

Comment: Another thing you should be looking at is that `except: pass`, a bad programming practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice

Answer (score 0):

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447)s are dynamically loaded. So you need to wait for the elements/texts to completely load before you attempt to extract them. Moreover you don't need to explicitly encode to *`utf-8`* as [by default *Python* uses `utf-8` encoding](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode).

---

### Solution

To print the **name** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *TAG_NAME*:

  ```
  #_*_coding: utf-8_*_
  # driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/abdullaev_parviz_zairhan_ogly/'})
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h3"))).text)
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  #_*_coding: utf-8_*_
  # driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/abdullaev_parviz_zairhan_ogly/'})
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  #_*_coding: utf-8_*_
  # driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://advpalata.vrn.ru/registers/reestr_lawyers/abdullaev_parviz_zairhan_ogly/'})
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Абдуллаев Парвиз Заирхан оглы
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Irrelevant in this context, element will be located with or without Wait. The issue was his encoding.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire Which part did you find irrelevant here? _WebDriverWait_?

Comment: That's correct, yes. His issue was not locating the element (although that XPATH is a little fragile, and he should select something more robust), his issue was the encoding.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire Sorry to say, that's a good approach using _requests_ / _BS4_, not _Selenium_ atleast.

Comment: You're mising the point: your response *does not* address the issue at hand, on this instance.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire _"his issue was the encoding"_: please [don't preach what you don't practice](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73129906/1)

Comment: return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Add a line at the top of your file `#_*_coding: utf-8_*_`

Comment: I donot understand where I add the line

Comment: Did you crosscheck the updated code snippets within my answer?

Comment: yes I check it will give same error

Comment: # -*- coding: UTF-8 -* when I add the they say utf not defined

Comment: Are you sure you have used `.visibility_of_element_located()`

Comment: yes  I  have edit the code check it