# element not interactable: [object SVGGElement] has no size and location error interacting with search field on YouTube homepage using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.action_builder import ActionBuilder
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


service = Service(executable_path="C:\\Users\\aps\\Desktop\\Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://youtube.com")


search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search).pause(2).click_and_hold().send_keys("Iktarfa").perform()
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-icon-legacy").click()
```

Search field is getting fetched.[image]

But after that I am getting following error, I am out of ideas and a new learner. Please HELP!!

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the page url?

Comment: Yes, it is https://youtube.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) which you have used:

```
(By.ID, "search")
```

identifies multiple elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

[image: youtube_search]

and the first [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) having the property `style="display: none;"`. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ytd-searchbox#search"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ytd-searchbox[@id='search']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, It was silly at my part. I did not check it. I presume that it is Id not class, so it will be used only one.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a Actions class for this scenario. It is perfectly capable of doing the search after just using the click and then searching for the element.

I used this code piece and it works perfectly fine

```
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

svc = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc,options=options)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://youtube.com")
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search")))

driver.find_element(By.NAME,'search_query').click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.NAME,'search_query').send_keys('Iktarfa')

button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-icon-legacy").click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

I've used the `sleep` method, but you should in general use an intelligent wait mechanism like Explicit waits.

Output screenshot -
[image]