# Scrapping using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape some data off a tweet

```
from selenium import webdriver
!pip install kora -q
from kora.selenium import wd

link = 'https://twitter.com/psalmcrypt/status/1442460419612835840?s=19'

wd.get(link)


for a in wd.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="id__armfsi35bm"]/div[2]/div/div/a'):
  promoter = a.get_attribute('href')

print(promoter)
```

I am getting the following error-

[image: Error]

I am copying the xpath from the inspector window

Comment: Which information are you attempting to scrape exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is used to iterate over a sequence i.e. either a `list`, a `tuple`, a `dictionary`, a `set` or a `string`.

In your usecase presumably it should have been a *`list`* of [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447)s. To return a *`list`* instead of `find_element()` you'd need `find_elements()` as follows:

```
for a in wd.find_elements(By.XPATH , 'xpath_of_the_elements'):
```

Comment: i use this in other way.
    
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , 'xpath/of_the/elements/*') 

This return a list of web elements so you can work by his positions. is pretty useful when you have troubles getting an element