# How to extract the link within the href attribute from the <a> element using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute, selenium-webdriver-python

How to get link with Selenium Python.

HTML sample:

```
<a herf="link" ...>
```

How to get this link in a variable.
I used many ways but didn't work. I used function `find_element()` example:

```
ele=bro.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value of any of the attributes of a *WebElement*, you have to use the [`get_attribute()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method from [**selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) module.

---

### This usecase

To extract the value of the *`href`* attribute from [WebElement(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) you can use the following line of code:

- From a single element:

  ```
  print(bro.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a').get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- From a list of elements:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')])
  ```

Comment: @AbdelrhmanKaamal You were trying to print href attribute from a list of elements so I have added that option as well.