# Trouble Scraping a loading score

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a score from a page.  But i honestly can't get myself on the path of getting anywhere close.  it's sandwich between a ::before after::.  Googling that has led me to probably needing selenium?  I've tried Beautiful Soup and Selenium but not getting anywhere.  Below is the best(it didn't return an error) that i've gotten.  But didn't return anything i can understand.  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d902be37b19adc23f00bcaa20ecfc885", element="4064ab3c-7da4-4223-b8bb-c2fbb6590cbe")>]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
URL = "https://coolcatsnft.com/user/0x10eb84abd429fa4df8dcabbc7c2803822a5b82d9"

driver.get(URL)

search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"sc-8ce97ff6-2.cgjlQk")
print(search)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the site's API to grab it using just the `requests` library.  You just need to take the unique identifier from the end of the page url and append it to the API and then use json to extract the score.

```
import requests
import math
api = "https://prod.journey.coolcatsnft.com/v1/score/get/"
page = "https://coolcatsnft.com/user/0x10eb84abd429fa4df8dcabbc7c2803822a5b82d9"

request_url = api + page.split("/")[-1]


resp = requests.get(request_url)

data = resp.json()
score = data["result"]["overAllScore"]

print(score)
print(math.ceil(score))
```

output

```
115.5
116
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  will look in to json and api.

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d902be37b19adc23f00bcaa20ecfc885", element="4064ab3c-7da4-4223-b8bb-c2fbb6590cbe")>]
```

indicates the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386067/7429447) itself, where as you need to extract the text.

---

### Solution

To extract the text *`116`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coolcatsnft.com/user/0x10eb84abd429fa4df8dcabbc7c2803822a5b82d9')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Accept cookies']"))).click()
  time.sleep(15)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-8ce97ff6-2.cgjlQk"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coolcatsnft.com/user/0x10eb84abd429fa4df8dcabbc7c2803822a5b82d9')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Accept cookies']"))).click()
  time.sleep(15)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-8ce97ff6-2 cgjlQk' and text()]"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm getting a return of 0.  I will try to dig in and figure it out.